# How do I capture values from a regex?

Tags: java, regex

How do extract values from a regex where any placeholder can be rederenced by a `$number_of_occurance value`?

For example, I have a string `final_0.25Seg1-Frag1` and I want to find all matches of this string in a file with `0.25` as a wildcard, which I can do using

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile( "/vod/final_\\d+\\.\\d+Seg1-Frag1" );
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(data2[0]);
```

I want to retain the value of the value in `\\d+\\.\\d` and find which among all the matched lines has the biggest value in this position.

Comment: To make the question more implementation specific, I have a string like `final_0.25Seg1-Frag1` and I want to find all matches of this string in a file with 0.25 as a wildcard, which I can do using `Pattern regex = Pattern.compile( "/vod/final_\\d+\\.\\d+Seg1-Frag1" ); Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(data2[0]);` I want to retain the value of the value in \\d+\\.\\d and find which among all the matched lines has the biggest value in this position. I hope it is clear to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Pattern group](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Group.html)s ? You can iterate through these to identify matched subexpressions.

From the linked example. Matcher.[group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29)(0) is the complete expression.

```
CharSequence inputStr = "abbabcd"; // could be a String type
String patternStr = "(a(b*))+(c*)";

// Compile and use regular expression
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
boolean matchFound = matcher.find();

if (matchFound) {
    // Get all groups for this match
    for (int i=0; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        String groupStr = matcher.group(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: matcher.group(0) return full matching, not group, as i think

Comment: See the linked example. But I will clarify this answer

Comment: That's right: group(0) is always the full match, and then any defined groups will start with group(1).

Comment: could someone please write a pseudo example for my case, I find it a bit confusing.. I'm quite new to java. Thanks guys.

Comment: @jamie - I've copied the complete example above. The concept is very similar to Perl, except it's much more verbose :-( In your example above just wrap the \\d.. in brackets and get group(1)

Comment: ahhh I get it now...I'm more used to scripting than this type of programming. Just takes a bit more time for brain cells to fire.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi,
Just adding on the previous discussion, I have extracted what I want using a regex into a variable using groups, is there a way that I can use this variable as a part of a regex that follows the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

Please give an example. I guess you need to read Mathcer docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/Matcher.html. You can access capturing groups via `group` method.

Comment: Hi,
I have a specific example in the first post, could you please take a look at it and suggest whats best for my case.

Comment: Change your regez to `/vod/final_(\\d+\\.\\d+)Seg1-Frag1` and look for group 1.